# App "Minuet" issue

Tags: sound, kde

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2 (64 bit Linux).

Two days ago I downloaded and installed, from the Gnome Software Center, an app called: "Minuet", which is intended to help in the music educational process. This app is from the KDE group (https://minuet.kde.org/).

But... I cannot to get any sound from it!

I guess it is related with the fact that I don't see a black background rectangle in the lower left part of the screen of this app (where are all the sound controls).

There is a demo video of this app here: https://youtu.be/IxmyevpFErU

In that video you can see the black rectangle which I don't have in my installation.

What is wrong and/or missed here?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is your system fully updated?  Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was not a LTS release, and requires the addition of a PPA to get extended support for it. (https://ubuntustudio.org/2019/04/ubuntu-studio-18-04-extended-support/) I don't know if this would help, but if you haven't enabled the PPA I would suggest adding it.

Comment: My system is full updated (I have the additional PPA to get the "LTS" status).